# load JSON from rails controller to d3 .defer() function within javascript file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js

I have a rails app that uses d3 to produce a globe with cities on it. Currently the data for the cities are in a static json file called places.json. The places.json file is then being rendered to the rest of the d3 code within assets/javascripts through this snippet

```
 queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/assets/world-110m.json")
.defer(d3.json, "/assets/places.json")
.await(ready);
```

I would like to replace the "/assets/places.json" file with a controller that rendors dynamic json. I currently have the controller in operation and I have a post request that can get the json to the javascripts file below.

```
$.post( "/teams/to_geo_json", function( data ) {
   alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
});
```

where `/teams/to_geo_json` is the path to the controller. However when I put the controller path into the `.defer(d3.json, "/assets/places.json")` it does not work and I have no idea how to get the `$.post("/teams/to_geo_json")...` call to work with the rest of the d3.js code.

Comment: Define "does not work".  Any errors on the console?  If you do `queue().defer(d3.json, "/teams/to_geo_json").await(ready); function ready(error, places) { console.log(error); }`, any error?

Comment: Wow you just helped me solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I was getting a 404 error in the defer. In my routes I had a

```
   post "/teams/to_geo_json" => "teams#to_geo_json"
```

In the console, it was asking for a get method from defer(). I changed the route above to this:
           get "/teams/to_geo_json" => "teams#to_geo_json"

Once I changed that I still had issues where `localhost:3000/teams/to_geo_json` was going to `localhost:3000/teams/show/id` instead and it thought `to_geo_json`was the id which of course it could not find. So it errored out. To fix this I put

```
 get "/teams/to_geo_json" => "teams#to_geo_json"
```

above

```
resources :teams, :only => [:index, :show] do
   resources :users, :path => :teammates, :as => :teammates, :controller =>    "teammates"
 end
```

in my routes.rb folder